# Python CSV.. Outputting a CSV file to another CSV file with different number of columns

Tags: python, unix, csv, text-processing

I have a mass CSV file, that I'd like to do some calculations on several fields and output the result to another CSV file.

Let's imagine that I have 12 fields on my `file1.csv`.
Here is my sample code :

```
import csv
file1 = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';') #traffic

for record in file1:
    print record[0], int(record[1]) * int(record[4])
```

Now.. I would like to save  these rows in a new csv file.. But I got stuck there. 
`writerrow()` method only accept the whole row, and not a pattern like what I've put on my `for` loop.

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` takes an iterable.  You can easily compose a new row by creating a list

```
# new_csv_writer = open file for writing
for record in file1:
    new_csv_writer.writerow([record[0], int(record[1]) * int(record[4])])
```

The above will write a row with 2 columns

Comment: Awesome .. thanks for reminding that `writerow` gets an **iterable**